# Force deep auto encoder to overfit training data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data, autoencoder

I have a conditional auto encoder (python, tensorflow) trained on numerical data with a small number of samples (16), with 100 features.

I am trying to force my auto encoder to greatly overfit my training data (reproduce it close to exactly). How would I do this (in terms of # layers, complexity, epochs, learning rate, latent space size, etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why you would like to do it? Overfitting is generally easy to do, just make your hidden state large enough and don't stop training until the loss is near 0.

Comment: The model is performing badly now when shouldn't it overfit on a small number of samples? The numerical data is normalized between 0 and 1, do you have any recommendation on what activation function to use? Should the learning rate be high or low? thanks!